# What are my options for proof of travel itinerary when applying for a Brazilian visa on a US passport?

Tags: usa, visas, itineraries, brazil

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6545/444) is quite similar, but with different specifics.  Undoubtedly, some of the options still apply, but specifically, what are my options to satisfy the Brazillian Immigration Authority's requirement for a [travel itinerary](http://houston.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/tourist_visa.xml):

> **Itinerary:** copy of your round-trip ticket, booked itinerary(reservation) or letter from a travel agent under applicant’s name, with complete itinerary, flight number and arrival/departure dates and reservation code provided by the airline company;

What are the actual, enforced requirements for this itinerary?

- Will a hotel reservation suffice in this case?  The language of the requirement seems unclear.
- I probably won't be doing a round-trip flight in any case; most likely I'll fly either from the U.S. or Mexico into Brazil, then from Brazil to Peru.  Will this pose a problem?

Comment: Note that as of June 2019, [Brazil no longer requires citizens of the US to apply for a visa before arrival.](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/travel/us-travelers-no-longer-need-a-visa-to-visit-brazil/2019/03/21/b5e9991a-4a81-11e9-b79a-961983b7e0cd_story.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What they are looking for is that you have both the means and the intention to leave the country by the time your visa expires. Therefore, "round-trip" should be understood as "not one-way".

Therefore, you'll have to provide a copy of your tickets and flight itinerary, or a letter from your travel agent that contains all the details of your flight reservation. A hotel reservation won't suffice, since it doesn't say anything about you leaving again.

An email directly from the Brazilian Consulate in Houston confirms this:

> Dear Sir/Madam,
>
> You must present the ticket or reservation with your flight or cruise in and out of Brazil.
>   Origin and destination may be different as long as you are allowed to leave for the country of your outbound flight.
>
> Visa Department
>   Consulate General of Brazil in Houston, TX
>   visa.houston@itamaraty.gov.br

Answer (score 2):

For you to be on safe side **return tickets**, **hotel bookings** and **daily allowance** are the basics that you will need to cover.

Whenever you are entering Brazil you are required to **fill an immigration form**. There you can explain what itinerary you will be taking, if/when asked by the authorities. Even though you do not have a return ticket you are covered because you will be leaving to Peru.

If you have friends in the country the better since you might add them as contacts. Hotels details are also a must in this case.

Usually the customs are very relaxed, only requiring the date when you are leaving the country.

Answer (score -1):

Traditional flight ticket or any booking for that matter, was a two step process. Where the first step is "reservation" and the next step is "booking". The reservation stage is where you were able to get a flight itinerary which confirms the following details.

- ITA (Airport) codes from which the flight takes off and lands.
- Flight timings - confirming that a flight, was in fact available through that route.
- Flight number for that trip usually something like "AI121" or similar.

So the [visa application needs you to provide a flight itinerary](https://travelvisabookings.com/flight-itinerary-visa-application/) with the above details. This was just a print out from the travel agent and you were done. The travel agent charges a fee around $10 for this .

With the advent of online booking. the process is now just one step. Direct booking because the websites make money only when a "booking" is done. But the visa consulates have chosen to ignore this and still insist on a flight itinerary even though it is difficult to get hold of one .

So how do you get a flight itinerary for visa application ?

- Call the flight agent and get one .
- Make one yourself on word document . Though this has been rejected at times by Spain and US consulate
- Get one from any one of the online service providers. like [Flight itinerary for visa](https://travelvisabookings.com). I have used this a couple of times and they are good.
- Buy a refundable ticket. Though these can be super expensive. Specially when it is on short notice.

Comment: Do you plan to copy-paste the same answer verbatim on all questions for which it might be relevant?