# Is a Brazilian tourist visa tied to specific entry and exit ports and dates?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, brazil

Brazil requires that US Citizens have flight reservations prior to applying for a tourist visa.  Per the suggestions in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6545/444), I have found what I believe to be the most reasonable round-trip, fully-refundable flight into Brazil, from Miami (MIA) to Manaus (MAO).

If I were to purchase this ticket, get my visa, then cancel the ticket in favor of a discounted ticket from, say, Lima to Sao Paulo, would this create any issues with my visa, as my application would have said I was flying to and from different cities?

Would it also be a problem if I ended up entering Brazil a day or two later (if post-visa application prices have changed to make this financially advantageous).

My international travel is limited, but I would expect the visa simply to be valid from X date to Y date, and the ports of entry and exit would be immaterial. But I don't want to make a >US$1000 gamble on this assumption.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong in that some countries do (or at least did) issue visas tied to a specific entry port but I don't know about Brazil. But if you really do want to travel to Brazil by air and to book non-refundable tickets soon, why not buy the actual tickets and apply with that?

Comment: @Annoyed: Because I don't know which port(s) I'll be using to enter/exit the country until after the time when I need to apply for the visa.

Comment: @Annoyed: And it's good to know my concern was justified :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no mark on the Brazilian visa about which port you are expected to enter from. There shouldn't be any problem with securing different fair. They just don't want to issue you a visa without proof you can leave when you say you will.

Comment: I emailed the consulate to double-check, and they confirmed this.

Answer (score 2):

Lately, Brazilian visas are taking more time than expected. So, even with the correct ticket, you may need to change your plans. For US citizen, they will provide a 10 year multiple-entry visa (similar to the visa US provides to Brazilian). So, as soon as you get your visa, you can get any flight you want to arrive in Brazil and leave from any airport you need.

Comment: What does "more time than expected" mean? Weeks? Months? Is this delay due to the spike in visa applications due to the upcoming World Cup?

Comment: @Flimzy That, or it's in reciprocity to similar delays for Brazilians applying for US visas. That word "reciprocity" appears a lot in consular information pages for US citizens.

Comment: @Flimzy, for a specific time frame you should talk directly to the nearest consulate. They have very different time frames as far as I know. Last time I needed, as a Brazilian, it took me a month to get a letter that was supposed to be processed in 5 days.