# How much time should I budget to see Bonito and Pantanal?

Tags: planning, brazil, itineraries

Going to Campo Grande in March and slowly marching onward towards Cusco.

I'm working out my itinerary and trying to figure out how many days I should budget for the Mato Grosso del Sur in order to see both Bonito and Pantanal.

Is it possible to do this in like 4-5 days? We were thinking
day 1 - get in late on Campo Grande
day 2,3 - go on Pantanal tour, getting dropped off in Bonito
day 4,5 - spend time in Bonito
day 6 - take the bus, train etc. to Santa Cruz, Bolivia.

Is this realistic? Or should I just choose between Bonito or Pantanal?

Comment: Where are you arriving from? Bonito (BYO) has an airport and you can flight direct there if you want.

Comment: I'm arriving in Campo Grande. Couldn't get cheap flights into Bonito

Comment: Since you intend to go to Bolivia, this question - not related to yours - is probably useful: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23630/is-a-brazilian-tourist-visa-tied-to-specific-entry-and-exit-ports-and-dates