# Fully refundable flights from India to South Africa economy class

Tags: air-travel, bookings, cancellations, refunds

From a [previous](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68165/are-there-any-airlines-which-refund-fare-fully-in-case-you-dont-get-visa/) question it seems there are fully refundable tickets. Are such tickets there in economy class also ?

I tried some options on akbartravels.com but in most flights two-thirds costs seem to be surcharges and taxes which I guess would be non-refundable.

Am I reading it right ?

Comment: These two questions do not seem to be duplicates to me as one is about tactics in case your visa is denied and this one is about refundable tickets specifically.

Comment: @chx, ok, reopened

Comment: @chx and +1 for astuteness :)

Comment: I retagged to clear up the confusion.

Comment: Yes there are fully refundable economy class flights. Usually they are more expensive than discount business class so think carefully about if you need the flexibility. Some airlines apply a small fee to process the refund (usually less than US$20).

Comment: that route is remarkably cheap at the moment!  wild.

Comment: went and came but thanx to the wonderful community support, it was much less hassle-free than I expected, boarding, de-boarding, security, the works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tip: Only use search engines to find out who flies between the city pairs and use the airline website for actual booking, you will have a much better selection.

I happen to know Qatar has free-to-cancel tickets and on a random date it was actually cheapest on Kayak so I checked Mumbai-Johannesburg on  qatarairways.com and the fares / cancel fees in Economy Promo | Saver | Value | Flexi are 
19016 / 2340 | 21846/ 2005 | 30803 / 1340 | 45724 / 0 . So Economy Flexi is free to cancel but the 2.5 times cheaper Promo is not horrible to cancel either.

Etihad, another very cheap option has a similar price range of 20223-42033 INR but the cancel fees are much steeper, 7000-1000 -- even the most expensive ticket costs to cancel.

Since I searched kayak and it indicated Kenyan Airways as a cheap option as well, I first checked whether it's [safe](https://aviation-safety.net/database/operator/airline.php?var=5885) and it passed IATA IOSA so it's OK then checked the prices and I found three sources on their website giving contradictory information about whether the Economy Super Flex is free to refund or not. A call would be required.

Answer (score -1):

You can also find full refundable fly tickets out of India on http://www.jetairways.com/EN/IN/Home.aspx
There is no cancellation fee for the ECONOMY FLEXI and the cheapest options starts by 25 000 INR e.g. for flight Delhi - Bangkok