Concerns about purchasing tickets prior to visa approval
A friend of mine is currently in the process of applying for a Schengen C visa from Pakistan. One of the requirements is to submit a ticket along with the application.
However, he is hesitant to purchase a ticket before the visa is confirmed. The reason being, if his visa application is rejected, he would end up wasting money on a ticket that he won’t be able to use.
Could anyone please advise on the best way to handle this? Is there an alternative to buying a ticket before the visa approval?

Possible duplicate: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36568/what-ticket-reservation-do-i-need-for-a-schengen-visa, other relevant questions: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174136/can-one-get-a-refund-for-their-airplane-ticket-if-their-visa-is-rejected, https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68165/are-there-any-airlines-which-refund-fare-including-economy-class-fully-in-case/68554#68554 - voting to close as duplicate

Well, there’s no loss of money because most of the international airlines follow money back policy for the unused tickets. Depending on the duration, you can either get full refund or major portion of your ticket amount. You can always read the refund policy on the airline’s website.
Good Luck 

Only if you buy tickets which can be returned for money, the expensive ones. The cheaper ones mostly can not.
