# Booking cancelable flights

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, cancellations, refunds

Schengen visas require that I provide confirmed flight bookings. But I had a flight last week that I couldn't take because the visa was delayed. This has resulted in a lot of unnecessary costs. Now the consulate is asking me for new travel documents for a trip to Germany in the future. I want to book flights that are completely refundable in case I have to cancel if the visa is delayed.

Is there anyway I can book flights online and cancel them later? most airlines do not consider visa delays as a reason to refund canceled tickets and the most they can is allow you to reschedule at a fee.

For context I'd like to go to Germany.

Comment: You'd like to go to Germany, but where are you travelling from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? The Answer lists airlines which permit cancellation and refund if a visa is not issued. [Are there any airlines which refund fare (including economy class) fully in case you don't get visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68165/are-there-any-airlines-which-refund-fare-including-economy-class-fully-in-case)

Comment: Are you sure you are required confirmed flights at visa application? You may need the return ticket at entry point

Comment: @user25730 I am traveling from the UK but my passport is from Egypt

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi yes unfortunately. They recommend booking refundable tickets for this reason but I can't find anything that is fully refundable for more than 24 hrs. I tried booking a ticket that is refundable within 24 hours but had to cancel it before I hear back from the embassy, then they got in touch saying my booking does not exist.